# GitHub push error - 'git media update'

Tags: git, github, git-push

I've been working with the GitHub for Mac client. It has worked perfectly fine for two months. Yesterday, after a successful commit and push, my client closed itself then restarted. Since then I have been unable to push changes to my online repo.

In the client I receive the message "The git media pre-push hook is out of date. Please run `git media update`"

When I try to push from terminal I receive this message "git: 'media' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. error: failed to push some refs to '[my GitHub repo URL.git]'"

Is there a way to resolve these errors and get my local repo working again? I'd really rather not create a new local repo if at all possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like something has added a hook to your repository. I haven't figured out what software is responsible for this, but command you want to run from your project root is ...

```
mv .git/hooks/pre-push .git/hooks/pre-push.sample
```

Comment: I was getting `git: 'media' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` in my terminal but Googling that didn't bring me here. Googling the Github for Mac error did.

Comment: This worked for me, also got the 'git media is not a git command' response, any ideas why git is suggesting something that doesn't exist?