# Git push --tags results in 'media' not a git command

Tags: git, github

Running the following command:

```
git push --tags
```

Gives me the following result

```
git: 'media' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git'
```

Has anyone seen this before or have an ideas about how I could stop it happening?

Comment: Did you check the following?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422595/github-push-error-git-media-update

Comment: I didn't see that when I searched. Solved the problem - thanks